# Prevent C incomplete string matching from highlighting the rest of the code with the string color?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

Not sure I said it right, it's kinda hard to explain with words, so:

[image]

I don't know if syntax highlighting trying to be helpful here or what, it's definitely annoying and distracting. I simply don't want the rest of the code to be highlighting in the string color while I'm typing a string in a certain line. Some other editors/IDEs only let the current line be affected as opposed to everything that's after the first `"`

I've been staring at the syntax file for a while now trying to figure out what match/region/hi is responsible for this, disabling things here and there but no luck, here's the file:

```
" Vim syntax file
" Language: C
" Maintainer:   Bram Moolenaar <Bram@vim.org>
" Last Change:  2013 Jul 05

" Quit when a (custom) syntax file was already loaded
if exists("b:current_syntax")
  finish
endif

let s:cpo_save = &cpo
set cpo&vim

let s:ft = matchstr(&ft, '^\([^.]\)\+')

" A bunch of useful C keywords
syn keyword cStatement  goto break return continue asm
syn keyword cLabel      case default
syn keyword cConditional    if else switch
syn keyword cRepeat     while for do

syn keyword cTodo       contained TODO FIXME XXX

" It's easy to accidentally add a space after a backslash that was intended
" for line continuation.  Some compilers allow it, which makes it
" unpredictable and should be avoided.
syn match   cBadContinuation contained "\\\s\+$"

" cCommentGroup allows adding matches for special things in comments
syn cluster cCommentGroup   contains=cTodo,cBadContinuation

" String and Character constants
" Highlight special characters (those which have a backslash) differently
syn match   cSpecial    display contained "\\\(x\x\+\|\o\{1,3}\|.\|$\)"
if !exists("c_no_utf")
  syn match cSpecial    display contained "\\\(u\x\{4}\|U\x\{8}\)"
endif
if exists("c_no_cformat")
  syn region    cString     start=+L\="+ skip=+\\\\\|\\"+ end=+"+ contains=cSpecial,@Spell extend
  " cCppString: same as cString, but ends at end of line
  if !exists("cpp_no_cpp11") " ISO C++11
    syn region cCppString   start=+\(L\|u\|u8\|U\|R\|LR\|u8R\|uR\|UR\)\="+ skip=+\\\\\|\\"\|\\$+ excludenl end=+"+ end='$' contains=cSpecial,@Spell
  else
    syn region cCppString   start=+L\="+ skip=+\\\\\|\\"\|\\$+ excludenl end=+"+ end='$' contains=cSpecial,@Spell
  endif
  syn region    cCppOut2    contained start="0" end="^\s*\(%:\|#\)\s*\(endif\>\|else\>\|elif\>\)" contains=cSpaceError,cCppSkip
  syn region    cCppSkip    contained start="^\s*\(%:\|#\)\s*\(if\>\|ifdef\>\|ifndef\>\)" skip="\\$" end="^\s*\(%:\|#\)\s*endif\>" contains=cSpaceError,cCppSkip
else
  if !exists("c_no_c99") " ISO C99
    "syn match  cFormat     display "%\(\d\+\$\)\=[-+' #0*]*\(\d*\|\*\|\*\d\+\$\)\(\.\(\d*\|\*\|\*\d\+\$\)\)\=\([hlLjzt]\|ll\|hh\)\=\([aAbdiuoxXDOUfFeEgGcCsSpn]\|\[\^\=.[^]]*\]\)" contained
  else
    "syn match  cFormat     display "%\(\d\+\$\)\=[-+' #0*]*\(\d*\|\*\|\*\d\+\$\)\(\.\(\d*\|\*\|\*\d\+\$\)\)\=\([hlL]\|ll\)\=\([bdiuoxXDOUfeEgGcCsSpn]\|\[\^\=.[^]]*\]\)" contained
  endif
  "syn match    cFormat     display "%%" contained
  syn region    cString     start=+L\="+ skip=+\\\\\|\\"+ end=+"+ contains=cSpecial,cFormat,@Spell extend
  " cCppString: same as cString, but ends at end of line
  syn region    cCppString  start=+L\="+ skip=+\\\\\|\\"\|\\$+ excludenl end=+"+ end='$' contains=cSpecial,@Spell
endif

syn match   cCharacter  "L\='[^\\]'"
syn match   cCharacter  "L'[^']*'" contains=cSpecial
if exists("c_gnu")
  syn match cSpecialError   "L\='\\[^'\"?\\abefnrtv]'"
  syn match cSpecialCharacter "L\='\\['\"?\\abefnrtv]'"
else
  syn match cSpecialError   "L\='\\[^'\"?\\abfnrtv]'"
  syn match cSpecialCharacter "L\='\\['\"?\\abfnrtv]'"
endif
syn match   cSpecialCharacter display "L\='\\\o\{1,3}'"
syn match   cSpecialCharacter display "'\\x\x\{1,2}'"
syn match   cSpecialCharacter display "L'\\x\x\+'"

if !exists("c_no_c11") " ISO C11
  if exists("c_no_cformat")
    syn region  cString     start=+\%(U\|u8\=\)"+ skip=+\\\\\|\\"+ end=+"+ contains=cSpecial,@Spell extend
  else
    syn region  cString     start=+\%(U\|u8\=\)"+ skip=+\\\\\|\\"+ end=+"+ contains=cSpecial,@Spell extend
  endif
  syn match cCharacter  "[Uu]'[^\\]'"
  syn match cCharacter  "[Uu]'[^']*'" contains=cSpecial
  if exists("c_gnu")
    syn match   cSpecialError   "[Uu]'\\[^'\"?\\abefnrtv]'"
    syn match   cSpecialCharacter "[Uu]'\\['\"?\\abefnrtv]'"
  else
    syn match   cSpecialError   "[Uu]'\\[^'\"?\\abfnrtv]'"
    syn match   cSpecialCharacter "[Uu]'\\['\"?\\abfnrtv]'"
  endif
  syn match cSpecialCharacter display "[Uu]'\\\o\{1,3}'"
  syn match cSpecialCharacter display "[Uu]'\\x\x\+'"
endif

"when wanted, highlight trailing white space
if exists("c_space_errors")
  if !exists("c_no_trail_space_error")
    syn match   cSpaceError display excludenl "\s\+$"
  endif
  if !exists("c_no_tab_space_error")
    syn match   cSpaceError display " \+\t"me=e-1
  endif
endif

" This should be before cErrInParen to avoid problems with #define ({ xxx })
if exists("c_curly_error")
  syn match cCurlyError "}"
  syn region    cBlock      start="{" end="}" contains=ALLBUT,cCurlyError,@cParenGroup,cErrInParen,cCppParen,cCppBracket,cCppString,@Spell fold
else
  syn region    cBlock      start="{" end="}" transparent fold
endif

"catch errors caused by wrong parenthesis and brackets
" also accept <% for {, %> for }, <: for [ and :> for ] (C99)
" But avoid matching <::.
syn cluster cParenGroup contains=cParenError,cIncluded,cSpecial,cCommentSkip,cCommentString,cComment2String,@cCommentGroup,cCommentStartError,cUserLabel,cBitField,cOctalZero,@cCppOutInGroup,cNumber,cFloat,cOctal,cOctalError,cNumbersCom
if exists("c_no_curly_error")
  if s:ft ==# 'cpp' && !exists("cpp_no_cpp11")
    syn region  cParen      transparent start='(' end=')' contains=ALLBUT,@cParenGroup,cCppParen,cCppString,@Spell
    " cCppParen: same as cParen but ends at end-of-line; used in cDefine
    syn region  cCppParen   transparent start='(' skip='\\$' excludenl end=')' end='$' contained contains=ALLBUT,@cParenGroup,cParen,cString,@Spell
    syn match   cParenError display ")"
    syn match   cErrInParen display contained "^^<%\|^%>"
  else
    syn region  cParen      transparent start='(' end=')' end='}'me=s-1 contains=ALLBUT,cBlock,@cParenGroup,cCppParen,cCppString,@Spell
    " cCppParen: same as cParen but ends at end-of-line; used in cDefine
    syn region  cCppParen   transparent start='(' skip='\\$' excludenl end=')' end='$' contained contains=ALLBUT,@cParenGroup,cParen,cString,@Spell
    syn match   cParenError display ")"
    syn match   cErrInParen display contained "^[{}]\|^<%\|^%>"
  endif
elseif exists("c_no_bracket_error")
  if s:ft ==# 'cpp' && !exists("cpp_no_cpp11")
    syn region  cParen      transparent start='(' end=')' contains=ALLBUT,@cParenGroup,cCppParen,cCppString,@Spell
    " cCppParen: same as cParen but ends at end-of-line; used in cDefine
    syn region  cCppParen   transparent start='(' skip='\\$' excludenl end=')' end='$' contained contains=ALLBUT,@cParenGroup,cParen,cString,@Spell
    syn match   cParenError display ")"
    syn match   cErrInParen display contained "<%\|%>"
  else
    syn region  cParen      transparent start='(' end=')' end='}'me=s-1 contains=ALLBUT,cBlock,@cParenGroup,cCppParen,cCppString,@Spell
    " cCppParen: same as cParen but ends at end-of-line; used in cDefine
    syn region  cCppParen   transparent start='(' skip='\\$' excludenl end=')' end='$' contained contains=ALLBUT,@cParenGroup,cParen,cString,@Spell
    syn match   cParenError display ")"
    syn match   cErrInParen display contained "[{}]\|<%\|%>"
  endif
else
  if s:ft ==# 'cpp' && !exists("cpp_no_cpp11")
    syn region  cParen      transparent start='(' end=')' contains=ALLBUT,@cParenGroup,cCppParen,cCppBracket,cCppString,@Spell
    " cCppParen: same as cParen but ends at end-of-line; used in cDefine
    syn region  cCppParen   transparent start='(' skip='\\$' excludenl end=')' end='$' contained contains=ALLBUT,@cParenGroup,cParen,cBracket,cString,@Spell
    syn match   cParenError display "[\])]"
    syn match   cErrInParen display contained "<%\|%>"
    syn region  cBracket    transparent start='\[\|<::\@!' end=']\|:>' contains=ALLBUT,@cParenGroup,cErrInParen,cCppParen,cCppBracket,cCppString,@Spell
  else
    syn region  cParen      transparent start='(' end=')' end='}'me=s-1 contains=ALLBUT,cBlock,@cParenGroup,cCppParen,cCppBracket,cCppString,@Spell
    " cCppParen: same as cParen but ends at end-of-line; used in cDefine
    syn region  cCppParen   transparent start='(' skip='\\$' excludenl end=')' end='$' contained contains=ALLBUT,@cParenGroup,cParen,cBracket,cString,@Spell
    syn match   cParenError display "[\])]"
    syn match   cErrInParen display contained "[\]{}]\|<%\|%>"
    syn region  cBracket    transparent start='\[\|<::\@!' end=']\|:>' end='}'me=s-1 contains=ALLBUT,cBlock,@cParenGroup,cErrInParen,cCppParen,cCppBracket,cCppString,@Spell
  endif
  " cCppBracket: same as cParen but ends at end-of-line; used in cDefine
  syn region    cCppBracket transparent start='\[\|<::\@!' skip='\\$' excludenl end=']\|:>' end='$' contained contains=ALLBUT,@cParenGroup,cErrInParen,cParen,cBracket,cString,@Spell
endif

"integer number, or floating point number without a dot and with "f".
syn case ignore
syn match   cNumbers    display transparent "\<\d\|\.\d" contains=cNumber,cFloat,cOctalError,cOctal
" Same, but without octal error (for comments)
syn match   cNumbersCom display contained transparent "\<\d\|\.\d" contains=cNumber,cFloat,cOctal
syn match   cNumber     display contained "\d\+\(u\=l\{0,2}\|ll\=u\)\>"
"hex number
syn match   cNumber     display contained "0x\x\+\(u\=l\{0,2}\|ll\=u\)\>"
" Flag the first zero of an octal number as something special
syn match   cOctal      display contained "0\o\+\(u\=l\{0,2}\|ll\=u\)\>" contains=cOctalZero
syn match   cOctalZero  display contained "\<0"
syn match   cFloat      display contained "\d\+f"
"floating point number, with dot, optional exponent
syn match   cFloat      display contained "\d\+\.\d*\(e[-+]\=\d\+\)\=[fl]\="
"floating point number, starting with a dot, optional exponent
syn match   cFloat      display contained "\.\d\+\(e[-+]\=\d\+\)\=[fl]\=\>"
"floating point number, without dot, with exponent
syn match   cFloat      display contained "\d\+e[-+]\=\d\+[fl]\=\>"
if !exists("c_no_c99")
  "hexadecimal floating point number, optional leading digits, with dot, with exponent
  syn match cFloat      display contained "0x\x*\.\x\+p[-+]\=\d\+[fl]\=\>"
  "hexadecimal floating point number, with leading digits, optional dot, with exponent
  syn match cFloat      display contained "0x\x\+\.\=p[-+]\=\d\+[fl]\=\>"
endif

" flag an octal number with wrong digits
syn match   cOctalError display contained "0\o*[89]\d*"
syn case match

if exists("c_comment_strings")
  " A comment can contain cString, cCharacter and cNumber.
  " But a "*/" inside a cString in a cComment DOES end the comment!  So we
  " need to use a special type of cString: cCommentString, which also ends on
  " "*/", and sees a "*" at the start of the line as comment again.
  " Unfortunately this doesn't very well work for // type of comments :-(
  syn match cCommentSkip    contained "^\s*\*\($\|\s\+\)"
  syn region cCommentString contained start=+L\=\\\@<!"+ skip=+\\\\\|\\"+ end=+"+ end=+\*/+me=s-1 contains=cSpecial,cCommentSkip
  syn region cComment2String    contained start=+L\=\\\@<!"+ skip=+\\\\\|\\"+ end=+"+ end="$" contains=cSpecial
  syn region  cCommentL start="//" skip="\\$" end="$" keepend contains=@cCommentGroup,cComment2String,cCharacter,cNumbersCom,cSpaceError,@Spell
  if exists("c_no_comment_fold")
    " Use "extend" here to have preprocessor lines not terminate halfway a
    " comment.
    syn region cComment matchgroup=cCommentStart start="/\*" end="\*/" contains=@cCommentGroup,cCommentStartError,cCommentString,cCharacter,cNumbersCom,cSpaceError,@Spell extend
  else
    syn region cComment matchgroup=cCommentStart start="/\*" end="\*/" contains=@cCommentGroup,cCommentStartError,cCommentString,cCharacter,cNumbersCom,cSpaceError,@Spell fold extend
  endif
else
  syn region    cCommentL   start="//" skip="\\$" end="$" keepend contains=@cCommentGroup,cSpaceError,@Spell
  if exists("c_no_comment_fold")
    syn region  cComment    matchgroup=cCommentStart start="/\*" end="\*/" contains=@cCommentGroup,cCommentStartError,cSpaceError,@Spell extend
  else
    syn region  cComment    matchgroup=cCommentStart start="/\*" end="\*/" contains=@cCommentGroup,cCommentStartError,cSpaceError,@Spell fold extend
  endif
endif
" keep a // comment separately, it terminates a preproc. conditional
syn match   cCommentError   display "\*/"
syn match   cCommentStartError display "/\*"me=e-1 contained

syn keyword cOperator   sizeof
if exists("c_gnu")
  syn keyword   cStatement  __asm__
  syn keyword   cOperator   typeof __real__ __imag__
endif
syn keyword cType       int long short char void
syn keyword cType       signed unsigned float double
if !exists("c_no_ansi") || exists("c_ansi_typedefs")
  syn keyword   cType       size_t ssize_t off_t wchar_t ptrdiff_t sig_atomic_t fpos_t
  syn keyword   cType       clock_t time_t va_list jmp_buf FILE DIR div_t ldiv_t
  syn keyword   cType       mbstate_t wctrans_t wint_t wctype_t
endif
if !exists("c_no_c99") " ISO C99
  syn keyword   cType       _Bool bool _Complex complex _Imaginary imaginary
  syn keyword   cType       int8_t int16_t int32_t int64_t
  syn keyword   cType       uint8_t uint16_t uint32_t uint64_t
  syn keyword   cType       int_least8_t int_least16_t int_least32_t int_least64_t
  syn keyword   cType       uint_least8_t uint_least16_t uint_least32_t uint_least64_t
  syn keyword   cType       int_fast8_t int_fast16_t int_fast32_t int_fast64_t
  syn keyword   cType       uint_fast8_t uint_fast16_t uint_fast32_t uint_fast64_t
  syn keyword   cType       intptr_t uintptr_t
  syn keyword   cType       intmax_t uintmax_t
endif
if exists("c_gnu")
  syn keyword   cType       __label__ __complex__ __volatile__
endif

syn keyword cStructure  struct union enum typedef
syn keyword cStorageClass   static register auto volatile extern const
if exists("c_gnu")
  syn keyword   cStorageClass   inline __attribute__
endif
if !exists("c_no_c99")
  syn keyword   cStorageClass   inline restrict
endif
if !exists("c_no_c11")
  syn keyword   cStorageClass   _Alignas alignas
  syn keyword   cOperator   _Alignof alignof
  syn keyword   cStorageClass   _Atomic
  syn keyword   cOperator   _Generic
  syn keyword   cStorageClass   _Noreturn noreturn
  syn keyword   cOperator   _Static_assert static_assert
  syn keyword   cStorageClass   _Thread_local thread_local
  syn keyword   cType       char16_t char32_t
endif

if !exists("c_no_ansi") || exists("c_ansi_constants") || exists("c_gnu")
  if exists("c_gnu")
    syn keyword cConstant __GNUC__ __FUNCTION__ __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ __func__
  endif
  syn keyword cConstant __LINE__ __FILE__ __DATE__ __TIME__ __STDC__
  syn keyword cConstant __STDC_VERSION__
  syn keyword cConstant CHAR_BIT MB_LEN_MAX MB_CUR_MAX
  syn keyword cConstant UCHAR_MAX UINT_MAX ULONG_MAX USHRT_MAX
  syn keyword cConstant CHAR_MIN INT_MIN LONG_MIN SHRT_MIN
  syn keyword cConstant CHAR_MAX INT_MAX LONG_MAX SHRT_MAX
  syn keyword cConstant SCHAR_MIN SINT_MIN SLONG_MIN SSHRT_MIN
  syn keyword cConstant SCHAR_MAX SINT_MAX SLONG_MAX SSHRT_MAX
  if !exists("c_no_c99")
    syn keyword cConstant __func__
    syn keyword cConstant LLONG_MIN LLONG_MAX ULLONG_MAX
    syn keyword cConstant INT8_MIN INT16_MIN INT32_MIN INT64_MIN
    syn keyword cConstant INT8_MAX INT16_MAX INT32_MAX INT64_MAX
    syn keyword cConstant UINT8_MAX UINT16_MAX UINT32_MAX UINT64_MAX
    syn keyword cConstant INT_LEAST8_MIN INT_LEAST16_MIN INT_LEAST32_MIN INT_LEAST64_MIN
    syn keyword cConstant INT_LEAST8_MAX INT_LEAST16_MAX INT_LEAST32_MAX INT_LEAST64_MAX
    syn keyword cConstant UINT_LEAST8_MAX UINT_LEAST16_MAX UINT_LEAST32_MAX UINT_LEAST64_MAX
    syn keyword cConstant INT_FAST8_MIN INT_FAST16_MIN INT_FAST32_MIN INT_FAST64_MIN
    syn keyword cConstant INT_FAST8_MAX INT_FAST16_MAX INT_FAST32_MAX INT_FAST64_MAX
    syn keyword cConstant UINT_FAST8_MAX UINT_FAST16_MAX UINT_FAST32_MAX UINT_FAST64_MAX
    syn keyword cConstant INTPTR_MIN INTPTR_MAX UINTPTR_MAX
    syn keyword cConstant INTMAX_MIN INTMAX_MAX UINTMAX_MAX
    syn keyword cConstant PTRDIFF_MIN PTRDIFF_MAX SIG_ATOMIC_MIN SIG_ATOMIC_MAX
    syn keyword cConstant SIZE_MAX WCHAR_MIN WCHAR_MAX WINT_MIN WINT_MAX
  endif
  syn keyword cConstant FLT_RADIX FLT_ROUNDS
  syn keyword cConstant FLT_DIG FLT_MANT_DIG FLT_EPSILON
  syn keyword cConstant DBL_DIG DBL_MANT_DIG DBL_EPSILON
  syn keyword cConstant LDBL_DIG LDBL_MANT_DIG LDBL_EPSILON
  syn keyword cConstant FLT_MIN FLT_MAX FLT_MIN_EXP FLT_MAX_EXP
  syn keyword cConstant FLT_MIN_10_EXP FLT_MAX_10_EXP
  syn keyword cConstant DBL_MIN DBL_MAX DBL_MIN_EXP DBL_MAX_EXP
  syn keyword cConstant DBL_MIN_10_EXP DBL_MAX_10_EXP
  syn keyword cConstant LDBL_MIN LDBL_MAX LDBL_MIN_EXP LDBL_MAX_EXP
  syn keyword cConstant LDBL_MIN_10_EXP LDBL_MAX_10_EXP
  syn keyword cConstant HUGE_VAL CLOCKS_PER_SEC NULL
  syn keyword cConstant LC_ALL LC_COLLATE LC_CTYPE LC_MONETARY
  syn keyword cConstant LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME
  syn keyword cConstant SIG_DFL SIG_ERR SIG_IGN
  syn keyword cConstant SIGABRT SIGFPE SIGILL SIGHUP SIGINT SIGSEGV SIGTERM
  " Add POSIX signals as well...
  syn keyword cConstant SIGABRT SIGALRM SIGCHLD SIGCONT SIGFPE SIGHUP
  syn keyword cConstant SIGILL SIGINT SIGKILL SIGPIPE SIGQUIT SIGSEGV
  syn keyword cConstant SIGSTOP SIGTERM SIGTRAP SIGTSTP SIGTTIN SIGTTOU
  syn keyword cConstant SIGUSR1 SIGUSR2
  syn keyword cConstant _IOFBF _IOLBF _IONBF BUFSIZ EOF WEOF
  syn keyword cConstant FOPEN_MAX FILENAME_MAX L_tmpnam
  syn keyword cConstant SEEK_CUR SEEK_END SEEK_SET
  syn keyword cConstant TMP_MAX stderr stdin stdout
  syn keyword cConstant EXIT_FAILURE EXIT_SUCCESS RAND_MAX
  " Add POSIX errors as well
  syn keyword cConstant E2BIG EACCES EAGAIN EBADF EBADMSG EBUSY
  syn keyword cConstant ECANCELED ECHILD EDEADLK EDOM EEXIST EFAULT
  syn keyword cConstant EFBIG EILSEQ EINPROGRESS EINTR EINVAL EIO EISDIR
  syn keyword cConstant EMFILE EMLINK EMSGSIZE ENAMETOOLONG ENFILE ENODEV
  syn keyword cConstant ENOENT ENOEXEC ENOLCK ENOMEM ENOSPC ENOSYS
  syn keyword cConstant ENOTDIR ENOTEMPTY ENOTSUP ENOTTY ENXIO EPERM
  syn keyword cConstant EPIPE ERANGE EROFS ESPIPE ESRCH ETIMEDOUT EXDEV
  " math.h
  syn keyword cConstant M_E M_LOG2E M_LOG10E M_LN2 M_LN10 M_PI M_PI_2 M_PI_4
  syn keyword cConstant M_1_PI M_2_PI M_2_SQRTPI M_SQRT2 M_SQRT1_2
endif
if !exists("c_no_c99") " ISO C99
  syn keyword cConstant true false
endif

" Accept %: for # (C99)
syn region  cPreCondit  start="^\s*\(%:\|#\)\s*\(if\|ifdef\|ifndef\|elif\)\>" skip="\\$" end="$" keepend contains=cComment,cCommentL,cCppString,cCharacter,cCppParen,cParenError,cNumbers,cCommentError,cSpaceError
syn match   cPreConditMatch display "^\s*\(%:\|#\)\s*\(else\|endif\)\>"
if !exists("c_no_if0")
  syn cluster   cCppOutInGroup  contains=cCppInIf,cCppInElse,cCppInElse2,cCppOutIf,cCppOutIf2,cCppOutElse,cCppInSkip,cCppOutSkip
  syn region    cCppOutWrapper  start="^\s*\(%:\|#\)\s*if\s\+0\+\s*\($\|//\|/\*\|&\)" end=".\@=\|$" contains=cCppOutIf,cCppOutElse,@NoSpell fold
  syn region    cCppOutIf   contained start="0\+" matchgroup=cCppOutWrapper end="^\s*\(%:\|#\)\s*endif\>" contains=cCppOutIf2,cCppOutElse
  if !exists("c_no_if0_fold")
    syn region  cCppOutIf2  contained matchgroup=cCppOutWrapper start="0\+" end="^\s*\(%:\|#\)\s*\(else\>\|elif\s\+\(0\+\s*\($\|//\|/\*\|&\)\)\@!\|endif\>\)"me=s-1 contains=cSpaceError,cCppOutSkip,@Spell fold
  else
    syn region  cCppOutIf2  contained matchgroup=cCppOutWrapper start="0\+" end="^\s*\(%:\|#\)\s*\(else\>\|elif\s\+\(0\+\s*\($\|//\|/\*\|&\)\)\@!\|endif\>\)"me=s-1 contains=cSpaceError,cCppOutSkip,@Spell
  endif
  syn region    cCppOutElse contained matchgroup=cCppOutWrapper start="^\s*\(%:\|#\)\s*\(else\|elif\)" end="^\s*\(%:\|#\)\s*endif\>"me=s-1 contains=TOP,cPreCondit
  syn region    cCppInWrapper   start="^\s*\(%:\|#\)\s*if\s\+0*[1-9]\d*\s*\($\|//\|/\*\||\)" end=".\@=\|$" contains=cCppInIf,cCppInElse fold
  syn region    cCppInIf    contained matchgroup=cCppInWrapper start="\d\+" end="^\s*\(%:\|#\)\s*endif\>" contains=TOP,cPreCondit
  if !exists("c_no_if0_fold")
    syn region  cCppInElse  contained start="^\s*\(%:\|#\)\s*\(else\>\|elif\s\+\(0*[1-9]\d*\s*\($\|//\|/\*\||\)\)\@!\)" end=".\@=\|$" containedin=cCppInIf contains=cCppInElse2 fold
  else
    syn region  cCppInElse  contained start="^\s*\(%:\|#\)\s*\(else\>\|elif\s\+\(0*[1-9]\d*\s*\($\|//\|/\*\||\)\)\@!\)" end=".\@=\|$" containedin=cCppInIf contains=cCppInElse2
  endif
  syn region    cCppInElse2 contained matchgroup=cCppInWrapper start="^\s*\(%:\|#\)\s*\(else\|elif\)\([^/]\|/[^/*]\)*" end="^\s*\(%:\|#\)\s*endif\>"me=s-1 contains=cSpaceError,cCppOutSkip,@Spell
  syn region    cCppOutSkip contained start="^\s*\(%:\|#\)\s*\(if\>\|ifdef\>\|ifndef\>\)" skip="\\$" end="^\s*\(%:\|#\)\s*endif\>" contains=cSpaceError,cCppOutSkip
  syn region    cCppInSkip  contained matchgroup=cCppInWrapper start="^\s*\(%:\|#\)\s*\(if\s\+\(\d\+\s*\($\|//\|/\*\||\|&\)\)\@!\|ifdef\>\|ifndef\>\)" skip="\\$" end="^\s*\(%:\|#\)\s*endif\>" containedin=cCppOutElse,cCppInIf,cCppInSkip contains=TOP,cPreProc
endif
"syn region cIncluded   display contained start=+"+ skip=+\\\\\|\\"+ end=+"+
"syn match  cIncluded   display contained "<[^>]*>"
syn match   cInclude    display "^\s*\(%:\|#\)\s*include\>\s*["<]" contains=cIncluded
"syn match cLineSkip    "\\$"
syn cluster cPreProcGroup   contains=cPreCondit,cIncluded,cInclude,cDefine,cErrInParen,cUserLabel,cSpecial,cOctalZero,cCppOutWrapper,cCppInWrapper,@cCppOutInGroup,cNumber,cFloat,cOctal,cOctalError,cNumbersCom,cString,cCommentSkip,cCommentString,cComment2String,@cCommentGroup,cCommentStartError,cParen,cBracket,cMulti
syn region  cDefine     start="^\s*\(%:\|#\)\s*\(define\|undef\)\>" skip="\\$" end="$" keepend contains=ALLBUT,@cPreProcGroup,@Spell
syn region  cPreProc    start="^\s*\(%:\|#\)\s*\(pragma\>\|line\>\|warning\>\|warn\>\|error\>\)" skip="\\$" end="$" keepend contains=ALLBUT,@cPreProcGroup,@Spell

" Highlight User Labels
syn cluster cMultiGroup contains=cIncluded,cSpecial,cCommentSkip,cCommentString,cComment2String,@cCommentGroup,cCommentStartError,cUserCont,cUserLabel,cBitField,cOctalZero,cCppOutWrapper,cCppInWrapper,@cCppOutInGroup,cNumber,cFloat,cOctal,cOctalError,cNumbersCom,cCppParen,cCppBracket,cCppString
if s:ft ==# 'c' || exists("cpp_no_cpp11")
  syn region    cMulti      transparent start='?' skip='::' end=':' contains=ALLBUT,@cMultiGroup,@Spell
endif
" Avoid matching foo::bar() in C++ by requiring that the next char is not ':'
syn cluster cLabelGroup contains=cUserLabel
syn match   cUserCont   display "^\s*\I\i*\s*:$" contains=@cLabelGroup
syn match   cUserCont   display ";\s*\I\i*\s*:$" contains=@cLabelGroup
syn match   cUserCont   display "^\s*\I\i*\s*:[^:]"me=e-1 contains=@cLabelGroup
syn match   cUserCont   display ";\s*\I\i*\s*:[^:]"me=e-1 contains=@cLabelGroup

syn match   cUserLabel  display "\I\i*" contained

" Avoid recognizing most bitfields as labels
syn match   cBitField   display "^\s*\I\i*\s*:\s*[1-9]"me=e-1 contains=cType
syn match   cBitField   display ";\s*\I\i*\s*:\s*[1-9]"me=e-1 contains=cType

if exists("c_minlines")
  let b:c_minlines = c_minlines
else
  if !exists("c_no_if0")
    let b:c_minlines = 50   " #if 0 constructs can be long
  else
    let b:c_minlines = 15   " mostly for () constructs
  endif
endif
if exists("c_curly_error")
  syn sync fromstart
else
  exec "syn sync ccomment cComment minlines=" . b:c_minlines
endif

" Define the default highlighting.
" Only used when an item doesn't have highlighting yet
"hi def link cFormat        cSpecial
hi def link cCppString      cString
hi def link cCommentL       cComment
hi def link cCommentStart   cComment
hi def link cLabel      Label
hi def link cUserLabel      Label
hi def link cConditional    Conditional
hi def link cRepeat     Repeat
hi def link cCharacter      Character
hi def link cSpecialCharacter   cSpecial
hi def link cNumber     Number
hi def link cOctal      Number
hi def link cOctalZero      PreProc  " link this to Error if you want
hi def link cFloat      Float
"hi def link cOctalError        cError
"hi def link cParenError        cError
"hi def link cErrInParen        cError
"hi def link cCommentError  cError
"hi def link cCommentStartError cError
"hi def link cSpaceError        cError
"hi def link cSpecialError  cError
"hi def link cCurlyError        cError
hi def link cOperator       Operator
hi def link cStructure      Structure
hi def link cStorageClass   StorageClass
hi def link cInclude        Include
hi def link cPreProc        PreProc
hi def link cDefine     Macro
"hi def link cIncluded      cString
"hi def link cError     Error
hi def link cStatement      Statement
hi def link cCppInWrapper   cCppOutWrapper
hi def link cCppOutWrapper  cPreCondit
hi def link cPreConditMatch cPreCondit
hi def link cPreCondit      PreCondit
hi def link cType       Type
hi def link cConstant       Constant
hi def link cCommentString  cString
hi def link cComment2String cString
hi def link cCommentSkip    cComment
hi def link cString     String
hi def link cComment        Comment
hi def link cSpecial        SpecialChar
hi def link cTodo       Todo
"hi def link cBadContinuation   Error
hi def link cCppOutSkip     cCppOutIf2
hi def link cCppInElse2     cCppOutIf2
hi def link cCppOutIf2      cCppOut2  " Old syntax group for #if 0 body
hi def link cCppOut2        cCppOut  " Old syntax group for #if of #if 0
hi def link cCppOut     Comment

let b:current_syntax = "c"

unlet s:ft

let &cpo = s:cpo_save
unlet s:cpo_save
" vim: ts=8
```

I would appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: You want what cCppString does, but not on cpp lines.

Comment: I'm sorry what? could you elaborate?

Comment: The *simplest* way to solve it would be for you to add both the `"` (start, end) from the beginning and write your text between the quotes. The problem of simply highlighting an incomplete string is that you *may* forget to add the final separator - Vim will show something which isn't true - a string which is ... not a string. A solution that solves both issues would be to highlight only the current line, but with a *different* color (as error? warning?) etc. - but then, perhaps you do have a quote on the next line, and Vim should look there too etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the string match in `cs.vim` (C# syntax) file, couldn't be simpler!

```
start=+"+  end=+"+ end=+$+
```

Replaced all the `cString` matches in my `c.vim` with it.

Comment: Or just use a plugin such as [delimtMate](https://github.com/Raimondi/delimitMate) or [auto-pairs](https://github.com/jiangmiao/auto-pairs) to close the quotes for you.

Comment: I used to use such plugins but found them more annoying at most times than helpful where you just want to have the open brace/quote without its closed counterpart which you end up deleting.

Comment: I would further refine it by adding `except=/\"/` in between 'start=' and 'end='.